# How internally UserDefinedRepository implements method by extending JpaRepository in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Suppose I have interface UserDetailRepository which extend JpaRepository in which I have 1 method

`findByUsername` which I have not implemented, still I get the result. How internally spring boot manages to implement method?

```
public interface UserDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

     Optional<User> findByUsername(String name);

}
```

Comment: Its a feature of the spring framework. you can write lot of query methods like this (without implementation). Read more in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend taking a look at [Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) section of the reference guide.

For instance, when you want to find User by user name, you would use method name like findByUsername(String name) which would translate into a condition like `select * from user where username = "name"`.

The query creation mechanism for JPA works as described in [Query methods here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods).